How to replace values based on another column in Power Query
I'm trying to replace values in one column based on values that start with 'monthly_Total' within another column but I can't seem to get it to work. I imagine I've done something silly but I can't see it
My code as follows:
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Renamed Columns",
each [Catagory],
each if Text.Start(Text.From([Description]),1) = "monthly_Total" then "Accounting Adjustments" 
else [Catagory],
Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Catagory"})

The 'Catagory' column contains the values I want to change to 'Accounting Adjustments' and the description column is the column that has the 'monthly_Total' values in

Text.Start(xxx,1) returns a single character . It will never match monthly_Total which is 13 characters if I count right, You need ,13

could you pls provide some sample data and expected output
